# X Display on windows machine

Tags: xorg, display, architecture

I am trying to learn the basics of Linux architecture. Therefore my following question aims at understanding the theory and architecture, not at a howto.

My understanding:
An graphic application runs on a remote Linux machine (e. g. LibreOffice).
While this is like the actual "application server" machine to me, we speak of a Display **Client** (e. g. X client) here.
A "client" machine (that a user sits in front of) hosts the Display **Server** which displays to the user (e. g. keyboard and screen).
The DISPLAY variable on the application server points to the client machine's display server.
So far correct?
What is the role of putty with X11 forwarding on a windows machine (the client machine to me) in this architecural setting?
This I just don't get.
Speaking of X I would think,  installing an X server implementation for Windows ( e. g. xming) on the win client machine and pointing the DISPLAY variable on the Linux machine to that Display server should be sufficient to display the application's graphic in an xming frame
Please help to understand the logic.
Thanks

Comment: Why not just try it, and learn on the way ? Or make a question on a problem you have encountered in your tests.

Comment: As I said. I don't have a problem. I just want to understand the principle.

Comment: <deleted double posting>

Comment: ask ubuntu is not the right place for your post but this is https://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/top-10-communities-to-help-you-learn-linux

Comment: yes, but how do you set the `DISPLAY` variable on the Linux machine? And how do you run programs on the Linux machine from inside Windows? You need a way to do that, which you can do in PuTTY.

Comment: Thanks for both replies. Yes, putty as a tool for accessing the variable I can understand. But for this x11 forwarding isn't necessary.

Comment: Trond, thanks for the hint. I will ask there too

Comment: However @trondhansen: your link lists askubuntu as an example. :-)

Comment: @bpn It says "AskUbuntu.com is another community for Ubuntu Linux users" - which you are not :)

Comment: This site is focused on Ubuntu-specific questions. Consider asking in https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://serverfault.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't related directly to Ubuntu. This question belongs rather to Server Fault or Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to try myself at a little reply. Feel free to ask about some more details.

The X-Window system dates back to the times where mainframes were more of a thing than today. Back then, in corporate and academic environments, it was very common that people didn't have a true computer on their desktop but only a *terminal device*, whose job was to manage 1) the display to the user, 2) input from the user, and 3) remote communication with a *central computer*, or mainframe, running application programs. At first, those terminal devices were text-only, but there was a need for a more elaborate display, and that's where X comes into play.

So, in X terminology, and in the mainframe model, the *Display Server* is a program that runs on the terminal device in front of the user. It waits for incoming connections (hence its name of server) from *X programs* running on the mainframe. By default, the X Program connects to the X server that's pointed to by the `DISPLAY` environment variable.

In a properly configured environment, the user doesn't have to set the `DISPLAY` variable by hand : the X terminal device sends a request to a *Display Manager* that runs on the mainframe (not to be confused with the display server that runs on the terminal, on the user's desktop), using a protocol that's called XDMCP (X Display Manager Control Protocol). The display manager program sends back a login screen, the user authenticates, and the display manager sets the `DISPLAY` variable, as well as possibly some security mechanisms, and in turn calls the *Session Manager*, still on the mainframe, that manages the user's session.

Now in practice, most people running X servers on Windows don't set up a true X-Window session. I'm not even sure it's possible with free X servers on Windows, as the only truly working ones that implement XDMCP are probably non-free (but maybe it changed, I don't know)... so they just start the X server on Windows, login with a text-only method such as Putty, then set the `DISPLAY` environment variable or simply use X11 forwarding.

Speaking of which, what is X11 forwarding ? It's a way to convey the connection from the X application program (on the remote machine) to the X server (on your desktop) through the SSH connection established by putty, hence ensuring it can't be eavesdropped on or tampered with (because yes, X-Window hasn't really been designed with confidentiality in mind). Putty asks the SSH server on the remote machine to open a listening TCP port, the `DISPLAY` variable is set to point to that port, and all connections to that port go through the SSH connection.

Comment: Dear NovHak , thanks so much. This was exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for! You wrote: "so they just start the X server on Windows, login with a text-only method such as Putty, then set the DISPLAY environment variable". So this means if I don't care about security, I would simply use putty to start the programs on my Linux specifying the display server, as @Esther said.

Comment: @bpn You can indeed set the `DISPLAY` variable to point to the X server directly (no security), or you can use X11 forwarding on Putty, though now that I think of it, I'm not quite sure it's available under that name on Putty, but rather the more general case of SSH port forwarding, of which X11 fwd is a particular case, in which case you have to set up the remote port number, the address+port it's redirected to (local I suppose), and set `DISPLAY` manually accordingly so that it goes through the tunnel.

Comment: Thanks NovHak. I am now beginning ng to understand the display server principle. Thanks to Esther too.